# Missing drivers while installing windows 10 on USB driver created on MAC

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, windows-installation, chipset

While installing Windows 10 form a USB flash drive, I got this error:

> A media driver your computer needs is missing. This could be a DVD,
>   USB or Hard disk driver. If you have a CD, DVD or USB flash drive with
>   the driver on it, please insert it now.
>
> Note: If the installation media for Windows is in the DBD drive or on a USB drive, you can safely remove it for this step.

I tried from all USB ports, both 2.0 and 3.0 and that didn't work.
[Here](https://youtu.be/xNIdOs_50r4?t=2m55s) they talk about downloading and placing drivers for Intel Rapid Storage Technology on the USB drive, however my motherboard has an AMD B450 Chipset. What would be the equivalent drivers?

Also, any other ideas how I can circumvent this error?

Comment: Jon - Check out https://www.amd.com/en/support/chipsets/amd-socket-am4/b450 and see if any of those drivers help with this issue. Based on the vague detail you provided per your situation here, this seems to be what you need. If you have something more specific if these do not help, consider disclosing the make and model of the PC or else the make and model of the motherboard I suppose if it's a custom built PC or one with parts from various other machines.

Answer (score -3):

I used a different technique to create the USB bootable drive, and it worked!

[Method that didn't work](https://youtu.be/Nhgjqbq_zYA)

[Method that worked](https://youtu.be/gxYASTJxC5o)